# Using fluentreports to add multiple tables

Tags: node.js

I have three arrays "listA, listB, listC" and I want to create three tables from those lists. So far I have only been able to create a single table and I I haven't been able to figure out how to do what I want with the documentation. [fluentreports documentaiton](http://www.fluentreports.com/docs.html)

Here is what I have so far, I was looking at .addReport and tried using it but I am getting an error "Unhandled rejection TypeError: rpt.addReport is not a function". Can I please get some help to display multiple tables. My code is below.

```js
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../config/db');
const router = new express.Router();
const PDFDocument =  require('pdfkit') 
const Report = require('fluentreports').Report

var fs = require("fs")


router.get('/getpdf', (req, res) => {
  res.type('application/pdf');
   // Our Simple Data in Object format: 
  
  var results1;

  db.sequelize.query("SELECT device.\"deviceID\", device.\"deviceType\", event.data, event.\"event_time_stamp\" FROM  public.device, public.event WHERE  event.\"device_deviceID\" = device.\"deviceID\"").spread((results, metadata) => {
    

      //console.log(results)
      var listA = [];
      var listB = [];
      var listC = [];
      results.map(cv => {
        switch (cv.deviceType) {
          case 'type1':
            listA.push(cv);
            break;
          case 'type2':
            listB.push(cv);
            break;
          case 'type3':
            listC.push(cv);
            break;
            
          }
      });
    
   
   
    listA.map(cv => {
  [cv.quantity, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Poison Grizach';
  cv.quantity = cv.quantity + '%'
  delete cv.data;
});
    listB.map(cv => {
  [cv.mouse, cv.rat, cv.other, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Non-Poison Grizach';
  delete cv.data;
});
    listC.map(cv => {
  [cv.flies, cv.quantity, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Insect Lamp';
  cv.flies =  cv.flies + '%'
  delete cv.data;
});
   var all = listA.concat(listB).concat(listC)
   

 var headerFunction = function(Report) {
        Report.print("Device Scans", {fontSize: 22, bold: true, underline:true, align: "center"});
        Report.newLine(2);
        Report.band([
          {data: 'Device Type', width: 100},
          {data: 'Quantity', width: 50},
          {data: 'Mouse', width: 50},
           {data: 'Rat', width: 50},
          {data: 'Other', width: 50},
          {data: 'Additional', width: 50},
          {data: '% Myxi', width: 50},
      ]);
    };
// Create a Report   
  var rpt = new Report(res,({fontSize: 10}))     
        .pageHeader( ["Device Scans"] )     // Add a simple (optional) page Header...         
        .margins(40)
        .data( listA )               // Add some Data (This is required) 
        .pageHeader(headerFunction) 
        .detail( [ ['deviceType', 100], ['quantity', 50] , ['mouse', 50], ['rat', 50], ['other', 50], ['additional', 50] , ['flies', 50]]) // Layout the report in a Grid of 200px & 50px 
        .render()

  var rpt2 = new Report(res,({fontSize: 10}))     
        .pageHeader( ["Device Scans"] )     // Add a simple (optional) page Header...         
        .margins(40)
        .data( listB )               // Add some Data (This is required) 
        .pageHeader(headerFunction) 
        .detail( [ ['deviceType', 100] , ['mouse', 50], ['rat', 50], ['other', 50], ['additional', 50] ]) // Layout the report in a Grid of 200px & 50px 
  

    rpt.addReport(rpt2)

  })  




       

  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is included below. The parent report rpt is included in the creation of the "sibling" reports. Render is called from the last sibling in this implementation with the option of isSibling: true. The header files are defined to give the column names

Get Request:

```js
router.get('/getpdf', (req, res) => {
  res.type('application/pdf');
   // Our Simple Data in Object format: 
 

  db.sequelize.query("SELECT device.\"deviceID\", device.\"deviceType\", event.data, event.\"event_time_stamp\" FROM  public.device, public.event WHERE  event.\"device_deviceID\" = device.\"deviceID\"").spread((results, metadata) => {
    

      //console.log(results)
      var listA = [];
      var listB = [];
      var listC = [];
      results.map(cv => {
        switch (cv.deviceType) {
          case 'type1':
            listA.push(cv);
            break;
          case 'type2':
            listB.push(cv);
            break;
          case 'type3':
            listC.push(cv);
            break;
            
          }
      });
    
   
   
    listA.map(cv => {
  [cv.quantity, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Poison Grizach';
  cv.quantity = cv.quantity + '%'
  delete cv.data;
});
    listB.map(cv => {
  [cv.mouse, cv.rat, cv.other, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Non-Poison Grizach';
  delete cv.data;
});
    listC.map(cv => {
  [cv.flies, cv.quantity, cv.additional] = cv.data.split(','); 
  cv.deviceType =  'Insect Lamp';
  cv.flies =  cv.flies + '%'
  delete cv.data;
});
   var all = listA.concat(listB).concat(listC)
   

 var headerFunction = function(Report) {
        
       
        Report.newLine(2);
        Report.band([
          {data: 'Device Type', width: 100},
          {data: 'Quantity', width: 50},
          {data: 'Additional', width: 50},
          
      ]);
};
 var headerFunction2 = function(Report) {
        
        Report.newLine(2);
        Report.band([
          {data: 'Device Type', width: 100},
          {data: 'Mouse', width: 50},
          {data: 'Rat', width: 50},
          {data: 'Other', width: 50},
          {data: 'Additional', width: 50},
          

      ]);
};
 var headerFunction3 = function(Report) {
        
        Report.newLine(2);
        Report.band([
          {data: 'Device Type', width: 100},
          {data: 'Burned Bulbs', width: 80},
          {data: '% Flies', width: 50},
          {data: 'Change Board', width: 80},
          

      ]);
};

// Create a Report   
  var rpt = new Report(res,({fontSize: 10}))
        .titleHeader("Device Scans")
        .margins(40)
        .data( {})               // Add some Data (This is required) 
       

  var rpt1 = new Report(rpt,({fontSize: 10}))
        .margins(40)
        .data( listA )               // Add some Data (This is required) 
        .pageHeader(headerFunction) 
        .detail( [ ['deviceType', 100], ['quantity', 50] , ['additional', 50]]) // Layout the report in a Grid of 200px & 50px       

  var rpt2 = new Report(rpt, ({isSibling: true}))     
        .margins(40)
        .data( listB )               // Add some Data (This is required) 
        .pageHeader(headerFunction2) 
        .detail( [ ['deviceType', 100] , ['mouse', 50], ['rat', 50], ['other', 50], ['additional', 50] ]) // Layout the report in a Grid of 200px & 50px 
        

  var rpt3 = new Report(rpt, ({isSibling: true}))     
         .pageHeader( ["Device Scans"] )
        .margins(40)
        .data( listC )               // Add some Data (This is required) 
        .pageHeader(headerFunction3) 
        .detail( [ ['deviceType', 100] , ['quantity', 80] , ['flies', 50] ,['additional', 80] ]) // Layout the report in a Grid of 200px & 50px 
        .render()

   
  })
```